# Magento ver. 2.1.7 not saving category getting exception

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

```
[2017-07-03 10:52:17] main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
    G
    eneral error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('pocketgr_pglvdb'@'localhost') does not exist'
      in D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228

    Stack trace:
    #0 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #2 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #3 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #4 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #5 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #6 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #7 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #8 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Db\UpdateRow.php(83): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('pg_catalog_cate...', Array, Array)
    #9 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update\UpdateMain.php(57): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Db\UpdateRow->execute('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
    #10 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update.php(105): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update\UpdateMain->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
    #11 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\EntityManager.php(87): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
    #12 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category.php(1027): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #13 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #14 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
    #15 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
    #16 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags.php(71): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #17 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #18 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
    #19 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category.php(43): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #20 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category.php(29): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #21 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #22 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
    #23 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Model\AbstractModel.php(631): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #24 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
    #25 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
    #26 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save.php(203): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
    #27 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save->execute()
    #28 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #29 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #30 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #31 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
    #32 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #33 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #34 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
    #35 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #36 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #37 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #38 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #39 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #40 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #41 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
    #42 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #43 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #44 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #45 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #46 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #47 D:\wamp\www\PG\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
    #48 {main}

    Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('pocketgr_pglvdb'@'localhost') does not exist, query was: UPDATE `pg_catalog_category_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `parent_id` = ?, `path` = ?, `level` = ?, `children_count` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '70')' in D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:235
    Stack trace:
    #0 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #4 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #5 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #6 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE `pg_cata...', Array)
    #7 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Db\UpdateRow.php(83): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('pg_catalog_cate...', Array, Array)
    #8 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update\UpdateMain.php(57): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Db\UpdateRow->execute('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
    #9 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update.php(105): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update\UpdateMain->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
    #10 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\EntityManager\EntityManager.php(87): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
    #11 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category.php(1027): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #12 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #13 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
    #14 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
    #15 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags.php(71): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #16 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #17 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
    #18 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category.php(43): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #19 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category.php(29): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #20 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #21 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
    #22 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Model\AbstractModel.php(631): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
    #23 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
    #24 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
    #25 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save.php(203): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
    #26 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save->execute()
    #27 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #28 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #29 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #30 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
    #31 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #32 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #33 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
    #34 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #35 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #36 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #37 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #38 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #39 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #40 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
    #41 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #42 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #43 D:\wamp\www\PG\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #44 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #45 D:\wamp\www\PG\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #46 D:\wamp\www\PG\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
    #47 {main} [] []
```

Comment: flow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 – Quick**

Simply create the missing MySQL user and that should solve the problem.

**Solution 2 – Magento Official**

The official Magento solution involves running a MySQL dump but using an empty string for the definer. Give this a try first before using Solution 3.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/live/stage-prod-migrate.html

**Solution 3**

Solution 3 has the same concept of replacing the definer string – but instead using the find and replace function in your favourite text editor after the database backup file has been created.

1) Create a backup of the database (mysqldump or phpadmin)

2) Open the backup file in your favourite editor (i.e. Notepad – not recommend for large databases mind you).

3) Find `user`@`localhost` (i.e. what Magento reports in the error as the first screenshot of this post).

4) Replace that with `newuser`@`newhost` (a user that has permissions for the database).
 - i.e. `root`@`localhost` or `root`@`127.0.0.1` or `root`@`dbserveripaddress`

5) Save the Sql file.

6) Re-import the database backup.